# ms access stops working when I open query having 20 million records with one sort

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have a query which combines different tables without any link so it create combination .Numbers of records has reached 20 Million , I have sorted these records by one field . MS Access hangs and stops working .Please anyone who can help in speeding up query or make it working.Thanks

Comment: With those numbers you need to move to a grown up RDBMS.

Comment: Can you share more details about the source data?  Access does have a size limit, have you tried adding one at a time and seeing how the DB increases in size?  Are they in separate DB's or the same one?

Comment: To handle such a large JOIN, you would need quite a lot of free space. If possible, try refining your query so that as much as possible irrelevant combinations are discarded. Also, do the source tables have suitable indices?

Comment: Access size limit is not reached yet . Currently it is at 500MB so this is not the case I think .Problem comes when I add sort criteria on one field

Comment: @FDavidov They were actually more than 500 Million I filtered them out to 20 Million.Tables are also normalized .Query works fine if I dont add any criteria ( It just show 20 million ) But If I add sort to see top of one field , access does not support

Comment: Sounds like you're using a butter knife when you need a steak knife.  You should look into upgrading the database backend to something more reasonable.  Access really isn't designed to handle that much data.

Comment: @HamzaRehmanSaleemi, I fully agree with user2388842. To the best of my recollection (you may wish to google on this), access has a limit to the size of a query response.

Answer (score 2):

Combining tables without telling the query how to relate one table to another is called a "cross join" as you say it creates a combination of the records.

It's easy to get very large results using a cross join, just 5000 rows in each of two tables in a cross join will generate 25 million records, just 300 records in each of three tables will give 27 million. With just 5000 or 300 records per table MSAccess will fly, but asking it to run a query to create ~20M records will take time, that's just how it is.

I suggest you tell us what you are trying to do, I expect that there should be a relationship between the tables, or at least something in the query to tell MSAccess which of the 20M records you want to see. I expect you don't want to scroll through 500000 or so pages of data to find what you are looking for.

Comment: I have players in different tables and I am making a combination of teams ( I have already tried different method query is the fastest to make combination )

 I have made combination of teams which are 600 million initially but after different criteria I filtered them to 20 Million.

Now I want to see top teams based on there score , So When I apply sort to field of score  (Descending order) It stops working .

Comment: Think about what you're actually telling it to do.  You're telling it to look at the (presumably calculated) score.  It has to calculate out the score for each of the 20 million records and push the ones with the highest scores to the top and order the rest of them in the same way.  That's a lot of work, especially for a tool that's not particularly well designed to handle large sets of data.  What you CAN try is to do a `top 50` (or 20...or 100) on your records, that way you're not pulling back ALL of the data, and only the data you're interested in....this may still be slow though.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to change your query to a *create-table* query using no filters.

Then create indexes in the new table on the fields you wish to filter on.

Now, use this table as source in a query where you apply the filters you wish.